# USB don't show on fdisk

Tags: linux, linux-mint, usb, usb-drive

I have a USB and for some reason i can't access it. 
On `fdisk -l` i don't see the USB, also not show on gparted or anywhere....

I don't remember the format of the usb.

Kernel version: 4.15.0-50-generic
Linux mint 19.1 Tessa

> lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 047: ID 0c76:0005 JMTek, LLC. Transcend Flash disk
```

> /var/log/syslog

```
kernel: [105006.175480] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [105006.393886] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0c76, idProduct=0005
kernel: [105006.393891] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: [105006.393894] usb 3-1: Product: USB Mass Storage
kernel: [105006.393897] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: GENERIC 
kernel: [105006.394306] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
kernel: [105006.395406] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 45: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 45 was not an MTP device
upowerd[2036]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
upowerd[2036]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1
kernel: [105007.433602] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
kernel: [105007.433951] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
kernel: [105007.434516] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

> dmesg

```
[105180.262905] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 47 using xhci_hcd
[105180.481671] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0c76, idProduct=0005
[105180.481677] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[105180.481680] usb 3-1: Product: USB Mass Storage
[105180.481683] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: GENERIC 
[105180.482245] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[105180.482439] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[105181.505323] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[105181.506061] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[105181.506755] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

> fdisk /dev/sdc

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: No medium found
```

Gparted and Disks also fail to find the drive.

Any ideas ?

> Updates: Tried with another PC

I tried it in another PC, with Ubuntu Server the same problem.

I get this logs now with

> dmesg and syslog

```
[423902.952193] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[423903.109057] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=abcd, idProduct=1234
[423903.109066] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[423903.109073] usb 1-7: Product: UDisk           
[423903.109079] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: General 
[423903.109084] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: Љ
[423903.110095] usb-storage 1-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[423903.118610] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-7:1.0
```

I recreate I think how i failed the USB, but i want to tell if i can rescue it.

I was burn with dd some iso and because it was stack i kill the process and then it can't mount or see with fdisk -l.

Why this happens if you know ? I destroy the firmware ?

Sorry i am stupid :) :P

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean with "dir to access"? Have you tried `fdisk /dev/sdc`? The logfile suggests that no partitions were found. Otherwise you would have had a message like `sdc: sdc1` before the last log entry.

Comment: fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: No medium found

Comment: Do you have a Linux Live CD/USB stick to test if your system is the problem or your USB device?

Comment: I test other usb and is ok

Comment: I would try to test with a different system first. You can also try a different USB port. If the problem remains it might be a faulty USB device.

Comment: Not that it will necessarily help, but for completeness I'd recommend that you edit your question to show your output from fdisk -l.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: No medium found
```

Your USB stick is pretending to be a removable drive with no media inserted (like a CD-ROM drive with no disc).

Unfortunately, this is how some storage devices report that they've failed their internal self-diagnostics and cannot work any more.

Usually, it's not worth the time and effort to try "fixing" a failed USB stick: just throw it into the trash and get a new one. But if you really want, [flashboot.ru](https://flashboot.ru) is a site that collects various tools for analyzing USB sticks and reflashing their firmware (usually Windows tools).

You would have to first identify the controller chip used in the USB stick using [ChipGenius](https://flashboot.ru/files/file/448/) or [Flash Drive Information Extractor](https://flashboot.ru/files/file/362/), then try and find the appropriate firmware and flashing tool for it.

Although reflashing the USB stick controller may allow the stick to be usable again, reflashing may totally reset the stick's internal metadata, causing all the data stored to the disk to be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Always try this first (if you can see it in `lsusb` and `dmesg` but not `fdisk` for instance).

- Unplug the thumb drive.
- Update (`apt-get update && upgrade`) or (pacman -Syu`enter code here`) or whatever else you are using.
- Then just reboot

plug the usb back in and see if it's working.

Often times that's all it is. You can do this without rebooting, but sometimes you just want to get er dun!